# hasMany where parent has a parent with a particular value

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 levels of tables/classes:

Order

Order_Item

Associated_Item

I've a few relational methods working fine :

1) Order hasMany Order_Items

2) Order_Item hasOne Associated_Item

3) Associated_Item hasMany Order_Items

4) Order_Item belongsTo Order

Starting from the Associated_Item I want a method that returns all 'Order Items' if the 'Order' has been paid. It also needs to be paginated

I want to run

```
$order_items = $associated_item->paidOrderItems()->orderByDesc('meeting_date')->whereNull('archived')->paginate(10);
```

So far I've got:

```
class Associated_Item extends Model
{
    public function paidOrderItems()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Order_Item::class);
        }
}
```

It works but its missing the 'is the order paid' check

How do I go 'up' 2 'levels'?

I'm new to Laravel so I'm completely stuck here.

Many Thanks

Comment: In which model do you want to check if the order is paid?

Comment: Associated Item - basically I need to look 'up' two levels

Comment: Something like C->hasMany(B->hasOne(A->isPaid)) ?
Hopefully I've explained it right

Comment: As far as I remember you can join and filter, something along the lines of : 

       $this->hasMany(Order_Item::class)->join('Order')->where('paid', TRUE)->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->hasMany(Order_Item::class)->join('Order')->where('paid', TRUE)->get();

Thanks JMCampos